# Primefaces Dialog Focus

Tags: primefaces

Is there a special way to include the p:focus on dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set focus to the dialog by calling the show() method for that dialog.

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" widgetVar="ajaxDialog" width="0"
                  draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:graphicImage value="./images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```

set the focus with

```
ajaxDialog.show();
```

Comment: Hi Ziagl, I meant to set the focus to an input component inside a dialog component.

Answer (score 1):

You can set focus automatically when a dialog is shown, using the tag p:focus.

Example:

```
 <p:dialog id="myDialog">
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <p:focus context="myForm"/>
           <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userBean.username}/>
    </h:form>
 </p:dialog>
```

when you open the dialog, The first visible editable field will gain focus.

References:

- [PrimeFaces ShowCase - Focus](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml)